# Comparison using Ruby's .days.ago seems to use reverse logic

Tags: ruby, date, comparison

Can anyone help me make sense of this, please?
I am getting a very weird behaviour (reverse logic), when I am trying to use the following code.

```
require 'active_support/all'

c = {
 id: 5,
 years_of_experience: 4,
 github_points: 293,
 languages: ['C', 'Ruby', 'Python', 'Clojure'],
 date_applied: 5.days.ago.to_date,
 age: 26
}

c["date_applied"] > 15.days.ago.to_date - #works
c["date_applied"] < 15.days.ago.to_date - #doesnt work
```

`c["date_applied"]` gives a date value stored in a hash.

The latter makes more logical sense, but the first returns the right answer.

Comment: What are you trying to do here?

Answer (score 3):

The code's behavior is correct, but I think I understand the confusion.

You're reading

```
c["date_applied"] > 15.days.ago
```

as:

> Is the date applied more than 15 days ago?

and

```
c["date_applied"] < 15.days.ago
```

as:

> Is the date applied less than 15 days ago?

and it's giving you the reverse of the answer you expect, right?

---

**If that's the case**, you should take a moment to understand how time comparisons operate. When you type `date1 > date2`, you're actually saying,

> If I plot *date1* and *date2* on a number line with time increasing from left to right,
> is *date1* to the right of *date2*?

This is the same as when you type `2 > 1`. It means,

> If I plot 1 and 2 on a number line with the numbers increasing from left to right,
> is 2 to the right of 1?

---

Given that this is how time comparisons operate, let's reexamine your code.

```
require 'active_support/all'

c = { date_applied: 5.days.ago.to_date }

c[:date_applied] > 15.days.ago.to_date
```

Correctly interpreted, this says

> Is the date 5 days ago further rightward on a left-to-right timeline than the date 15 days ago?

and the answer is yes, or `true`.

If, on the other hand, you were to *incorrectly* interpret this as

> Is 5 days ago more than 15 days ago?

you would get (or expect to get) the mistaken answer of no, or `false`.

---

The correct way to think about the task in English is to reframe the question of

> <s>Is date *d* more than *n* days ago?</s>

and instead think of it as

> Is date *d* earlier than the date *n* days ago?

and the correct code becomes apparent:

```
d.to_date < n.days.ago.to_date
```

---

If I understood your question correctly, this should explain it.

Comment: Great answer, that should be marked correct and have more upvotes. I also find it counter-intuitive when thinking of the comparison as "more than"--which works fine with integers, but not date comparison. Rather than "more than," I can even start translating this to "to the right of."

Answer (score 1):

> irb ## ruby-1.9.3-p448

```
require 'active_support/time'

c = {
 id: 5,
 years_of_experience: 4,
 github_points: 293,
 languages: ['C', 'Ruby', 'Python', 'Clojure'],
 date_applied: 5.days.ago.to_date,
 age: 26
}
(c[:date_applied] > 15.days.ago.to_date) - #true
(c[:date_applied] < 15.days.ago.to_date) - #false
```

###or you can try it by adding your own private methods###

```
class Fixnum
  def days
     self * 60 * 60 * 24   # we store seconds in a day
  end
 
  def ago
    Time.now - self
  end
end
```